# Rewrite an expression in terms of basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal

Given any vector ***k*** $\epsilon$  $R^{3}$ consider ***k***= $\sum_{j=1}^{3}$ $c_{j}u_{j}$ where $u_{1}$,$u_{2}$,$u_{3}$ are the orthonormal basis vectors (I don't know how to make them **bold** sorry about that, but they are vectors). This means in the basis B the vector ***k*** looks like ($c_{1}$,$c_{2}$,$c_{3}$). Rewrite the expression (H**k**)$\cdot$ ***k***= .
$k^{T}$ H**k** in terms of the basis vectors B

We are given that H= \begin{bmatrix} -3&1  &2 \\  1&-3  &2 \\ 
 2& 2 & 0\end{bmatrix}

and B={$u_{1}$,$u_{2},$$u_{3}$} (u are vectors)

I have calculated $u_{1}$ $u_{2}$ $u_{3}$ but I'm not sure if this question needs them. 
I know this is quite a straightforward question of computation, but I have no idea how to rewrite the vector ***k*** in terms of B
so I know **k**=$c_{1}$$u_{1}$+$c_{2}$$u_{2}$+$c_{3}$$u_{3}$. Does it mean that 
k=($c_{1}$,$c_{2}$,$c_{3}$)B? And how should I deal with the dot product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the basis $B=\{u_1, u_2, u_3\}$ we have
$$ k=\left[ \begin{array}{c} c_1\\c_2\\c_3 \end{array}\right].$$
Hence
$$ Hk=\left[ \begin{array}{rrr} -3 & 1 & 2\\ 1 & -3 & 2\\2 & 2 & 0 \end{array} \right]
\left[ \begin{array}{c} c_1\\c_2\\c_3 \end{array}\right]=\left[ \begin{array}{c} -3c_1+c_2+2c_3\\c_1-3c_2+2c_3\\2c_1+2c_2 \end{array}\right] $$
and consequently
$$ (Hk)\cdot k=k^{T}Hk=(-3c_1+c_2+2c_3)c_1+(c_1-3c_2+2c_3)c_2+(2c_1+2c_2)c_3=$$
$$=-3c_{1}^{2}-3c_{2}^{2}+2c_1c_2+4c_1c_3+4c_2c_3.$$